# Heroku to salesforce update polling time control

Tags: trigger

I am new to Heroku. I want to know is there any way by which we can schedule the updates from heroku to salesforce. Currently I have created basic app in heroku and it is connected with one salesforce object. It is showing the heroku to salesforce update time 10 seconds. Can I schedule this time by any way?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Heroku provides the scheduler add ons by which we can schedule the update timings.
For more details:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler